# Formatting of numbers while finding remainder using Binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

While Dividing $$2^{501}$$ by 21 to find remainder why do we need to write it in the form of $$8(63+1)^{83}$$ and not like $$2(21-5)^{125}$$ like why should it always be in the form of (1+x) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it the second way, it is easy to see that
$$2(21-5)^{125}\equiv-2\times5^{125}\pmod{21}\ .$$
But this still leaves you a fair bit of work to do.  If you do it the first way, you get the final answer almost immediately.

Comment: Yeah i nearly forgot that part , thanks man